# AngularJS dynamic templates and replaceWith

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have directive with dynamic templates. After I use replaceWith method my addClass method do not take effect.

```
var template = '';
switch (scope.type) {

   case 'type1':
      template = '<div>Type1</div>';
      break;

   case 'type2':
      template = '<div>Type2</div>';
      break;
}

element.replaceWith(template);
element.addClass('test');
```

JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/L5z5Ld9u/1/

Comment: But class do not appear in div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work because element is fully replaced with template, so you shall add class to template, not to element:

```
var template;
switch (scope.type) {

  case 'type1':
    template = angular.element('<div>Type1</div>');
    break;

  case 'type2':
    template = angular.element('<div>Type2</div>');
    break;
}

element.replaceWith(template);
template.addClass('test');
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxL8x1a1/)

Comment: Ok. That is works. Then I add new element by click and I see <some-content> tag https://jsfiddle.net/6g35519z/1/